# Showing $E[\operatorname{Tr}(AAA^TA^T)]<E[\operatorname{Tr}(AA^TAA^T)]$ for Gaussian $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory

Suppose $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with IID standard normal entries, it appears the following holds, why?

$$E[\operatorname{Tr}(AAA^TA^T)]<E[\operatorname{Tr}(AA^TAA^T)]$$

More generally, it appears that grouping $A$ and $A^T$ together, gives smaller value of trace compared to interlacing them, is this a well known result? I found "disentangling lemma" in lecture [notes](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Ejrl/teaching/cse599Isp21/notes/lecture3.pdf) but it's for Hermitian matrices and the inequality is reversed -- interlacing matrices appears to reduce the value of trace

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Tr}[A.A.A.A.A.A.A.A] & 384 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A.A.A.A.A.A^T\right] & 432 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A.A.A.A^T.A^T.A^T\right] & 440 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A.A.A^T.A^T.A^T.A^T\right] & 464 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A.A.A^T.A.A.A^T\right] & 496 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A.A.A^T.A.A^T.A^T\right] & 504 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A.A.A.A^T.A.A^T\right] & 512 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A.A^T.A.A.A^T.A^T\right] & 520 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A.A^T.A.A.A.A^T\right] & 528 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A.A^T.A^T.A.A^T.A^T\right] & 544 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A.A^T.A.A^T.A^T.A^T\right] & 560 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A.A^T.A.A^T.A.A^T\right] & 664 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A^T.A.A^T.A^T.A.A^T\right] & 688 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A.A^T.A.A^T.A.A^T.A^T\right] & 720 \\
 \text{Tr}\left[A.A^T.A.A^T.A.A^T.A.A^T\right] & 1328 \\
\end{array}
$$

Computed using this Mathematica code

```
ClearAll[isCyclicOrTranspose, isCyclicPermutation];
numTerms = 8;
n = 2;

allTerms = Tuples[{A, A\[Transpose]}, numTerms];

(* Remove terms equivalent under trace symmetries *)
isCyclicPermutation[a_, b_] := 
  MemberQ[Table[RotateLeft[b, k], {k, 1, Length[b]}], a];
isCyclicOrTranspose[a_List, b_List] := 
  Or[isCyclicPermutation[a, b], 
   isCyclicPermutation[Transpose /@ a, b]];
exprs = DeleteDuplicates[allTerms, isCyclicOrTranspose];
exprs = Dot @@@ exprs;

getMoment[n_, expr_] := (
   traceExpr = Tr[expr] /. A -> Array[a, {n, n}];
   distSpec = # \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1] & /@ 
     Variables[traceExpr];
   Expectation[traceExpr, distSpec]
   );

vals = Table[getMoment[n, expr], {expr, exprs}];
poses = Ordering[vals];
{exprs, vals} = {exprs[[poses]], vals[[poses]]};
poses = First@Flatten@Position[vals, #] & /@ Union[vals];

TableForm[{TraditionalForm[Tr[#]] & /@ exprs[[poses]], 
   vals[[poses]]}\[Transpose]]
```

Comment: if these matrices had components in $\mathbb R$ instead, then you'd get the result from Cauchy-Schwarz or equivalently considering $\big \Vert A^TA - AA^T\big \Vert_F^2\geq 0$.  The latter approach may be preferable to show your strict inequality with components being iid r.v.s.

Comment: Oh! very elegant. I should remove my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be a square matrix of order $n$ and let $a^*$ be its transposed matrix. We show that $$\mathrm{trace}(a^2a^{*2})\leq \mathrm{trace}((aa^{*})^2).$$ to see this we write $a=udv^*$ in its polar form, where $u,v$ are orthogonal and $d$ is diagonal with nonegative elements. Using $w=uv^*$ we get $$\mathrm{trace}(a^2a^{*2})=\sum_{i,j}d_i^2w_{ij}^2d_j^2\stackrel{(*)} {\leq } \sum_id_i^4=\mathrm{trace}((aa^{*})^2)$$ To see (*) we use the fact that $(w^2_{ij})$ is a bistochastic matrix
and therefore is a convex combination of permutation matrices. Hence enough is to assume that $(w^2_{ij})$ is a permutation matrix. Without loss of generality we may assume that $d^2_i$ is non increasing. As a consequence, from Hardy Polya and Szego 'Inequalities' page 261 we have $$\sum_id_i^2d^2_{\sigma(i)}\leq \sum_id_i^4.$$